# How to prove it is uniformly bounded?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, inequalities, elliptic-pde

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain with smooth boundary. Say $\theta\in(0, 1]$. Let $u(x, \theta)$ be a solution to the problem $\Delta u-\theta u=g(x)$ subject to Neumann boundary condition. Suppose that $g\in C^\alpha(\Omega)$ and $\int_\Omega g(x)dx=0$. Can we find $M>0$ such that  $\|u(\cdot, \theta)\|_\infty\le M$ for any $\theta\in (0, 1]$.

I asked this question two days ago and nobody responds. I guess my question was not that clear. Could anyone help me with that?

Comment: You mean for $\Omega$ to be bounded? If so, more than this is true. You get bounds not just for $\|u\|_\infty$, but actually for $\|u\|_{2,\alpha}$. Look up Schauder estimates in any textbook on elliptic PDEs.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I do mean $\Omega$ is bounded. However, I am not sure about whether I can use Shaulder esimate because $\theta$ is a variable. If $g=1$, the solution is $-1/\theta$ which blows up at $\theta=0$.

Comment: Since you impose the condition of zero integral, the problem at $\theta=0$ disappears. It is matter of using standard results in perturbation theory. Kato's book is a good reference.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try to read Kato's book although it seems a little too much for me at my stage. I guess I am able to prove the Schauder estimate:  $\|u-1/|\Omega|\int u\|_{C^{2, \alpha}}\le C\|g\|_{C^\alpha}$ by contradiction.